# Does HTTP response goes through proxy?

Tags: http, kubernetes, networking, proxy

I have newbie question, I could not find the answer.

Let`s assume that I have 2 pods, each on different service in kubernetes. One pod must have set HTTP_PROXY.

When I make internal HTTP request beetwen services from proxy-pod to no-proxy-pod it won`t work, becouse proxy cannot reach internal IPs.

When I make internal HTTP requests beetwen services if I for example make HTTP GET from no-proxy-pod to proxy-pod -> does response from proxy-pod goes through proxy or directly?

Is there a way to decide if it goes through proxy or not?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to set the `NO_PROXY` environment variable to the list of hosts that should not use the proxy.

See this SuperUser question/answer for more details

https://superuser.com/questions/944958/are-http-proxy-https-proxy-and-no-proxy-environment-variables-standard